# how to make a request from JS to the server?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x

I have a frontend that is trying to make a post request to the server:

```
    sendData() {
        let url = "http://localhost:9090/example";
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: {value: 10}
        })
    }
```

And two backends Node.js and Python:

```
const express = require("express");
   
const app = express();
const jsonParser = express.json();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.listen(9090, function(){
    console.log("Connection...");
});

app.post("/example", jsonParser, function(req, res){
    console.log(req);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

```
import asyncio
 
async def test(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = await reader.readline()
        print(data)
        if not data:
            break
 
 
async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(test,'127.0.0.1', 9090 )
    await server.serve_forever()
asyncio.run(main())
```

In both cases, I want to save the value from the request to the server. However, servers only receive headers:

```
b'POST /example HTTP/1.1\r\n'
b'Host: localhost:9090\r\n'
b'Connection: keep-alive\r\n'
b'Content-Length: 15\r\n'
b'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"\r\n'
b'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\n'
b'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\n'
b'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"\r\n'
b'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\r\n'
b'Accept: */*\r\n'
b'Origin: null\r\n'
b'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site\r\n'
b'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors\r\n'
b'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty\r\n'
b'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n'
b'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\n'
b'\r\n'
```

Please guide me how can I get the sent value. This is necessary in order to subsequently write it to the database

Comment: Does [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) support objects in the body? Typically you would see `body: JSON.stringify(xyz)`. You may also need to indicate a header of `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: I have added this to the code. Node JS still has a body: {} and Python only shows headers

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript client and server examples work with Node.js.

Client:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

(async () => {
  const rc = await fetch("http://localhost:9090/example", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ cats: 42, dogs: 12 }),
  });
})();
```

Server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(9090, function () {
  console.log("Connection...");
});

app.post("/example", (req, res) => {
  console.log("body:", req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

And here's a very simple Python HTTP server (though not using asyncio):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn

class Example(BaseModel):
    cats: int
    dogs: int

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/example")
async def create_example(example: Example):
    print(example)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=9090)
```